# Handling self-refreshing pages (ajax) from selenium

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium.
I have same problem with for which you have already answered,

I have attached my code here and explained where I am getting ajax problem.
I just started building my framework, it is just a groundwork I am doing and and stuck.

I try to use your code, getting errors.

1. with session() method I am getting error (expecting object).
2. TIMEOUT

what am I need to do to run your methods.

with Selenium2 have we got any new functionalities that are dealing with Ajax?

Comment: Where is that attached code?